# Can I disable "Tab" keycode in ViewPager?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-viewpager

I implemented the onPageChangeListener in my ViewPager. When I connect the bluetooth keyboard to the device and strike the "Tab" key, the view pager will switch to next view automatically.

I am wondering is there any way that I can disable the "Tab" key action for the view pager? What I want is when I press "Tab" key on keyboard, the view pager won't switch to next view. But when I swipe use finger, it still switches.

```
 private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mPageChangeListener =
            new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (mCurrentView != null) {
                mIsScrolling = state != ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;
                mCurrentView.setIsScrolling(mIsScrolling);
            }
            if (mCallback != null) {
                mCallback.onScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (mCurrentView != null) {
                mCurrentView.setIsScrolling(false);
            }
            if (mCallback != null) {
                mCallback.showView(position);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into the source code of ViewPager, it's by design that when we press TAB, it will do arrowScroll(FOCUS_RIGHT) to next view. The only way I can think of is to create a custom viewpager, override the executeKeyEvent() function.

```
public boolean executeKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    boolean handled = false;
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                handled = arrowScroll(FOCUS_LEFT);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                handled = arrowScroll(FOCUS_RIGHT);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB:
                if (KeyEventCompat.hasNoModifiers(event)) {
                    handled = arrowScroll(FOCUS_FORWARD);
                } else if (KeyEventCompat.hasModifiers(event, KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_ON)) {
                    handled = arrowScroll(FOCUS_BACKWARD);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return handled;
}
```

Reference:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#ViewPager.executeKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29